# Adding a database to availability group is case insensitive and cause vss backup exclusions

Tags: sql-server

I was using a vss solution to take backup of my SQL availability group databases where I encountered a scenario when I have a database name like "TestDB" and when i added database to an availability group with name "testdb", caused exclusion of database from vss snapshots. As SQL is case insensitive and automatically handles lower and upper case databases if collation set to CI(Case insensitive).
Can someone please help if there is any guidelines to follow when we add database to an AG with Case Insensitive and Case sensitive server settings?

Comment: Provide us with results of `SELECT @@VERSION`

Comment: Version I am using is : "Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP1) (KB3182545) - 13.0.4001.0 (X64)   Oct 28 2016 18:17:30   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Enterprise Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2016 Standard 6.3 <X64> (Build 14393: ) (Hypervisor) "